# jquery changed current image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use this sample to create my virtual tour. http://www.openstudio.fr/lab/jQuery-virtual-tour,67.html?lang=en

In my body i use this code to create move right or left in my current image :

```
    <img id="my_image" src="img/sculpteur.jpg" class="advancedpanorama" width="2448" height="375"    usemap="testmap" alt="Atelier du sculpteur" />
       <map id="testmap" name="testmap">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1653,72,1839,255" href="index.html" alt="vers la salle de formation" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="2013,114,2091,210" href="img/statue1.jpg" alt="statues" class="thickbox" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="1920,276,2070,351" href="img/gouges.jpg" alt="gouges" class="thickbox" />
</map>
```

I use another code jequer to modify the current image by anothoer onClick event :

```
$('#my_image').on({
'click': function(){
    $('#my_image').attr('src','second.jpg');
}
});
```

but that dosn't work.
i tested this script for another image, it work!

how to fix this pb?
Thx,

---

@telford , I used your code but idsn't work!!

```
                <div class="content-left">
                    <div class="row1">
                        <h1 class="title">Welcome To <span>Our Site</span></h1>
                        <p class="title"><strong>Visitez </strong><span>notre société :pour cela,cliquez sur les lieux ci-dessous:bonne visite!</span></p>
                        <div id="page">     
                            <img src="img/s5.jpg" class="advancedpanorama" width="2448" height="375" usemap="testmap" alt="Salle de réunion" />
                            <map id="testmap" name="testmap">       
                                <area shape="rect" coords="2013,114,2091,210" href="ap2.php" alt="**********" class="thickbox" /> 
                                <area shape="rect" coords="1920,276,2070,351" href="ap.php" alt="***********" class="thickbox" /> 

                                <area shape="rect" coords="1653,72,1839,255" href="salleformation.html" alt="vers la salle de formation"/>
                                <area shape="rect" coords="1527,50,1653,114" href="p18/demo/new.html" alt="vers la salle de réunion"/>
                            </map>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <img id="my_image" src="s11.png"/>
            </div>
```

in the head, i have this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.panorama.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img.advancedpanorama").panorama({
                    auto_start: 0,
            start_position: 1527
             });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $('#my_image').on('click', function(){
        $(this).attr('src','s12.png');
      }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cvi_text_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.advanced-panorama.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flipv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.thickbox').fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

I have another question : is it possible to add the event click on the current image  to change the src attribute with jquery when another jquery javascript is applicated for this image??? my image and my code is http://www.openstudio.fr/lab/jQuery-virtual-tour,67.html?lang=en.. thx

Comment: Please, read http://api.jquery.com/on/ , jQuery have very well docs with examples.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's just a typo on here, but your jQuery code should be:

```
$('#my_image').on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('src','second.jpg');
  }
});
```

Comment: The [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method allows passing an object containing multiple events (instead of a single event name and handler), so I don't think this will solve the issue.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Maybe you should read the API Document. http://api.jquery.com/on/ - Quote: 'Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements'. That clearly says there it will handle single event handlers, which is what my answer is.

Comment: @TelfordComputer-DoctorLtd: it appears you've missed the second signature of `.on`, which clearly states that the OP's form is permitted.